# Computing the required thickness of an aluminum sheet to support a given load

Tags: aluminum

I want to fabricate an aluminum shelf for my media center. 22 1/16” x 37 5/8” with a rectangular cutout 2 1/2” deep on one of the long edges of the sheet with 6” of material on either side of the cutout. ([CAD model](https://cad.onshape.com/documents/57e301ae0e78317e9d4c2972/w/6cfbee75e3f4ecfea2f3e3bb/e/bc438004f0aa4347176726bf))

[image]

The shelf will be supported by four shelf pins on the short edges near the corners.

The question I need to answer is how thick the aluminum needs to be to support my intended load (100 lbs of equipment, more-or-less in the center).

I've been playing around with [SimScale](https://www.simscale.com/projects/MatthewYo/metal_shelf) and (assuming I'm doing it right) I've determined that a tenth of an inch of aluminum is sufficient, but I'd like a better methodology for computing the *minimum* required thickness than "guess and check".

What is the right way to compute the required thickness of the sheet of aluminum? Modelling the problem as a rectangle secured on the short edges with a 100 lb load in the center seems like the first step, but coming from a CS/EE background I'm lacking the statics knowledge to enable me to properly set up the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An adequate simplification would be to treat it as a simply supported beam (there is not much added benefit to treat it a plate).

For a simply supported beam with:

- Length L = 37 5/8''
- width w = 22 1/16'' - 2 1/2'' = 19 9/16''  (the width is at its thinness point)

Assuming the load is dead center:

$$M=P\cdot \frac{L}{2} = 1881.25 [lbf.in]$$
where:

- P is the load (100 lbf)

The maximum stress that will be developed is:

$$\sigma = \frac{M}{I}\frac{t}{2}$$

where:

- I is the second moment of area of the plate $I = \frac{w\cdot t^3}{12}$
- t is the thickness

the maximum stress needs to be less than the allowable stress:

$$\sigma_{all} \ge \sigma = \frac{12 M}{w\cdot t^3}\frac{t}{2}$$

Therefore
$$t \ge \sqrt{\frac{6 M}{w\cdot \sigma_{all} }} = \sqrt{\frac{2 P\cdot L}{w\cdot \sigma_{all} }}$$

Assuming you use 6061 which has a yield stress of 40000 psi with a safety factor of 1, then the minimum resulting thickness is 0.1201 inches (which is consisted with your calculations).

For comparison purposes, assuming you applied a safety factor of N=2 (therefore the $\sigma_{all}=\frac{40000}{N}=20000 [psi]$, the minimum thickness would be 1.7 inches.

### additional check with deflection.

Its best to check with deflection.

The max deflection for a simply supported beam with a concentrated load is:

$$d_{max} = \frac{P L^3}{48 EI}$$

where:

- $d_{max}$ is the max deflection. Usually, its defined as a fraction of the beam span length to avoid visible sagging (e.g. 1/250 L =0.1505'' ).
- $E$ is the elasticity modulus of aluminium = 10000 ksi

So again (after some algebra):

$$t = \sqrt[3]{\frac{12 P L^3}{48 E\cdot d_{max}\cdot w}}$$

If you apply the values, then the minimum thickness results in 0.3564 inches. **As you can see its double the minimum thickness when you calculate based on stresses**.

So, if you use 0.17 inches the shelf will not break, but it will have a noticeable by eye sag, which will not be pleasant.

Comment: Note to OP: when you get much thicker, it may make sense to construct the shelf out of multiple differently shaped pieces (like an I-beam or T-beam), instead of just a single sheet, to save on the weight and cost of the sheet

Comment: Or you can just add a stiffner at the edge (both sides of the long edges). It offers a significant improvement.

Comment: yes, that also counts as "multiple differently shaped pieces" and is probably a more sensible shape for a shelf.

Comment: So do rolled edges or a fold… that will change the deflection.